# При использовании общей библиотеки установка одного приложения на смартфон ведёт к уничтожению другого

Tags: android, gradle, library

Я создал новое приложение, использовав в нём библиотеку одного из предыдущих, указав в settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':classification'
project(':classification').projectDir = new File('C:\\base_android\\AndroidStudioProjects\\SPACE\\classification')
```

При этом в build.gradle нового проекта также прописал зависимость:

```
implementation project(':classification')
```

Библиотека подключилась. Проблема в том, что эти два проекта не могут сосуществовать одновременно на смартфоне. Когда на смартфоне стоит одно приложение и устанавливается другое, первое уничтожается.

Как это пофиксить, при этом так, чтобы не создавать *.jar или *.aar файл, так как в процессе разработки как одного, так и другого приложения постоянно возникает необходимость редактировать библиотеку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приложения уникально идентифицируются по пакету. Он указан в `applicationId` свойстве в `build.gradle` модуля приложения. Следовательно эти значения должны быть разными для разных приложений.